# getJSON with callback failing with Expected ';'

Tags: javascript, getjson

I am trying to use `jQuery.getJSON` to get information from a site using the following code.

```
<script>
var url = "https://www.gov.uk/api/foreign-travel-advice/usa.json";

alert(url);

$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?",null, function (json) {

alert(json);  
alert(json.details.description);
})

</script>
```

This returns an error in IE :
Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729) Timestamp: Thu, 9 May 2013 16:51:48 UTC

```
Message: Expected ';'
Line: 1
Char: 18
Code: 0
URI: https://www.gov.uk/api/foreign-travel-advice/usa.json?callback=jQuery1910011146073418833335_1368117826272&_=1368117826273
```

If I download usa.json as a file everything works fine.

From reading other answers, I think the problem is that the site does not support callbacks correctly.  As I have no control over the server, can anyone tell me how to get around this error?

Comment: You can't just get around the error/problem with JavaScript. You would have to use a local proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing JSON, and JSONP, which are two very different things.

[JSON](http://json.org) is a data notation. An object in JSON notation might look like this:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) is a transport mechanism for JSON that works around the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) by using `script` tags and a function call behind the scenes. The JSONP for the above might look like this:

```
callback({"foo": "bar"})
```

By putting `?callback` in your URL, you're telling jQuery to expect JSONP, not JSON.

If the API you're talking to doesn't support JSONP, you can't use JSONP with that API. You might be able to use [YQL as a proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax). Otherwise, unless that site supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (and a quick check suggests it doesn't) and you can rely on your users using a [CORS-enabled browser](http://caniuse.com#cors), you'll need to run this through your own server.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting YQL.  After a bit of messing about I am now getting valid JSON from the site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a semi - colon on the last line.

It should look like this:
    alert(json.details.description);
});